# Show that $\mathbb{T}^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is complete and compact with respect to given metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Show that $\mathbb{T}^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is complete and compact with respect to given metric.

let the metric $d: \mathbb{T}^n \times \mathbb{T}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $d(x+\mathbb{Z}^n, y+\mathbb{Z}^n)$ = inf$\{ \Vert{v-w}\Vert; v \in x+\mathbb{Z}^n, w \in y+\mathbb{Z}^n\}$.

Here is what I've trying to do:

Since $\mathbb{T}^n$ is defined as a coset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by relation such that $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y$ is an integer, I guess the element of $\mathbb{T}^n$ can be uniquely written such as $x+\mathbb{Z}^n=\bar x=(x_1,x_2, ..., x_n)$, where $0 \leq x_i \lt 1$ for each $i$ .

and the distance between two points $\bar x, \bar y \in \mathbb{T}^n$ should be $\Vert (x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2,...,x_n-y_n)\Vert$ where $0 \leq x_i,\, y_i \lt 1$ for each $i$.

I think that it is possible to consider each $i$-th component of cauchy sequence $(x_k)$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$ as a cauchy sequence $({x_i}_k)$ on $[0,1]$.

Since $[0,1]$ is complete, each $i$-th component should converge to some point, say $z_i$, and then we can show the cauchy sequence on $\mathbb{T}^n$ converge to the point $z=(z_1, z_2, ..., z_n)$.

Also I know that in the metric space, compactness is equal to completeness and totally boundedness, so if I can show this space is totally bounded, then the compactness will follow.

I'd like to see whether the my above argument is right or not, and know more simple argument to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Any compact metric space is complete.

Comment: Your distance formula is incorrect. When $n=1$ say, the distance between the cosets $0.1+\Bbb Z$ and $0.9+\Bbb Z$ is $0.2$, not the $0.8$ given by your formula.

Comment: You need to prove only compactness , since every compact metric is complete. Your idea is correct, in that you consider the unique members of each equivalence class which lie in $[0,1]^n$, and then use the fact that this space is complete in the usual metric to conclude. However, your argument needs to be written carefully, I can see some errors creep in, for example your distance formula.

Comment: And since the Tychonoff Theorem tells you that any product of compact spaces is compact, you are really reduced to proving that $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$ is compact.  Since you're only talking about a finite product, you don't even need the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks!

Comment: @RobertShore then if I show $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is compact, then by Tychonoff theorem, $\mathbb{T}^n$ should be compact too and the completeness will follow, right?

Comment: That's correct.  It might help your intuition to notice that $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$ is homeomorphic to a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the projection map $\pi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z^n$. It satisfies
$\|\pi(x)-\pi(y)\|\le\|x-y\|$, basically by definition, and so is Lipschitz
and therefore continuous. Then $\Bbb T^n=\pi([0,1]^n)$ is the continuous image 
of a compact set and so is compact. Compact metric spaces are complete.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm seeking. Btw what does its basis look like?